# How to return a map<std::string, unique_ptr> element and not loosing it?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class of `ConfigItem`:

```
// CConfigItems.hpp
template< typename T > class ConfigItem : public IConfigItem // IConfigItem is its inteface
{
private:
    T m_value;

public:
    ConfigItem< T >(const T& valueIn = 0) : m_value(valueIn) {}

    operator T() const
    {
        return T(m_value);
    }
};

typedef std::map< std::string, std::unique_ptr< IConfigItem > > ConfigMap;

template< typename T, typename ...Args > std::unique_ptr< T > make_unique(Args&& ...args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr< T >(new T(std::forward< Args >(args)...));
}
```

Then I have a class `ConfigFile` that has a map of `ConfigItem`s:

```
#include "CConfigItems.hpp"

class ConfigFile
{
private:
    ConfigMap m_configMap;

public:
    ConfigFile(const std::string& configFileNamePathIn)
    {
        PTree tmpPT;

        /// reading config file ///
        json::read_json(configFileNamePathIn, tmpPT);

        m_configMap.emplace("path.to.value", make_unique< ConfigItem< std::string > >(tmpPT.get< std::string >("path.to.value")));
        checkEmptyness(*m_configMap["path.to.value"]);
    }

    ConfigFile(ConfigFile&& configFile) : m_configMap(std::move(configFileIn.m_configMap)) {} // initially copy ctor

    std::string getClassifierCarFilePath()
    {
        return *m_configMap["path.to.value"];
    }
};
```

Of course I have more elements in the `ConfigMap` and of more different types. I had a copy constructor, but using `unique_ptr` make me change it to move, which is the problem of segmentation fault. Any suggestions of how to fix this?

---

Here the segmentation happens:

```
// ...
ConfigFile configFile(argv[2]);
std::shared_ptr< ISolution > solution;
initializeSolution(std::move(configFile), solution, displayer); // here the move destroys the m_configMap member. Then I am calling the getter
std::string clsfile = configFile.getClassifierCarFilePath();
// ...
```

So I am moving the ConfigFile object in a function, but I need it after that function. Is there a possibility to change `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr`?

Comment: why `return T(m_value);` if `m_value` is already of type `T`?

Comment: Please elaborate where you loose it, I don't see any code that returns a map element that you mentioned in the title.

Comment: BTW: Why doesn't `getClassifierCarFilePath` return a (`const`) reference?

Comment: @AndyT: 1. sorry, not necessary. 2. `checkEmptyness(*m_configMap["path.to.value"]);` does not delete the pointer? I get an Segmentation fault when calling the getter.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Why shall I return a const reference? Regarding [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/object_returning.php) the return shall be a reference only if you return an input parameter.

Comment: If you return an input-parameter, or something else with guaranteed longer lifetime. Which is the case here.

Comment: I have edited the question, I am always getting the segmentation fault, What is happening?

Comment: `m_configMap["path.to.value"]` returns a reference to `unique_ptr` which doesn't do anything with unique_ptr itself. Then you dereference it which also cannot release it. Please check what exactly causes your segmentation fault.

Comment: If I am doing `std::string s = std::string(*m_configMap["path.to.value"]);` in the constructor, `s` is containing the true value. But if I do a `return std::string(*m_configMap["path.to.value"]);` I am getting the segmentation fault. Any suggestions?

Comment: NOO!! The problem is that I had a copy ctor that I have changed to move ctor, so there is the problem. Any ideas of how I can make it shared_ptr instead of unique_ptr?

Comment: The real problem is the move ctor. How to make it back to copy?

Comment: Please show an MCVE. It is hard to understand where and when exactly the segfault happens.

Comment: @sop I think the `unique_ptr` part is OK. The problem might happen if you move the map, but still reuse the old map you moved from. Solution: rethink your use cases.

Comment: edited: to see the problem: move then use again. I cannot just reorder the code, because I have another function that needs the `configFile`

Comment: @sop run your code under `gdb`. When the segmentation fault happens, type `bt` followed by the enter key. The first function call inside your code contains the problem.

Comment: I have just shown the problem: I moved the configFile and then I need to use it again. How to fix this?

Comment: Well if you move configFile into initialize solution and still want to use it afterwards you need to rethink your initialization logic. Probably easiest would be to first real all values you need from your config file and then move it away...

Comment: Can't I just change unique_ptr with shared_ptr?