# Does slicing occur with unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, unique-ptr, object-slicing

I have a pointer which sliced, but I don't exactly know where and why.
There are two lines of code which I think could lead to splicing:

The creation of a unique pointer:

```
map.insert(make_pair("ChildA", unique_ptr<Base>(new ChildA())));
```

and the returning of raw pointer from my unique pointer:

```
return map["ChildA"].get();
```

note that:

- Class ChildA inherits Base
- Base has a virtual destructor
- the map in the example above is of type:

  ```
  map<string, unique_ptr<Base> >
  ```

Does splicing occur in either of the lines of code stated above? Is there an easy way to avoid where it does?

Comment: You meant `return map["ChildA"].get()` right ?

Comment: `return map[ChildA].get()` is not valid code - always [post REAL code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: IIRC, slicing only occurs on copies of value objects; so not references, and not pointers (even when in a smart pointer). So this would depend on what the type is in signature of the function that contains `return map[ChildA].get();`. What is the signature and how is the result used?

Comment: How do you know it is sliced? Why haven't you posted the relative errors? Please include an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of bits of code where you think the problem is.

Comment: If you did something like `Base foo() { return *(map["ChildA"].get()); }`, yes that would both slice and be simultaneously utterly hideous. Now post your *real* code.

Comment: There is no slicing in the code you've shown (after the substituion of `["ChildA"]` for `[ChildA]` to make it valid). Pointers can't slice.

Comment: It is not really the same, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26097428/3062311) will also help you a little. I had a copy ctor and then I have changed it to move ctor and then I just gave up, because I really need a copy ctor, and unique_ptr are not copyable.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry that was a typo. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

There is no slicing taking place in the code you've posted as far as I can see.

Demo: http://ideone.com/8InZ6H

Slicing will occur if you try to copy a `Child1` into a `Base` by value. Are you sure you're not doing that anywhere else in your code?